# What is the meaning of this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Instead of that, he had just sailed over a party of friends from his own place on the Long Island shore.
>   ([Link to source](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks02/0200571.txt))

How do you analyze this sentence? Does he go to a party of friends from his own place?
Is it same thing as "He had just sailed from his own place on the Long Island shore over a party of friends."?

If not, what is the proper understanding of this sentence?

Comment: *Sail* here is used like *drive*: if you have a car you drive your friends somewhere, if you have a boat you sail them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*A party of friends*" means *a **group** of friends*.

The sentence as a whole means that he had a rather large sailboat, which he used to transport *a **group** of friends* from his residence (*place*) "on the Long Island shore" to some other place (not mentioned in your excerpt).

Comment: the whole script is in the link, you can go to the link, and find the specific line there.

Comment: @aggressionexp: Yep. Just as I thought.